# Dynamically assign Database Document Properties

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "floatingPeriodLength"
```

When I POST to `addPricingRule` I don't pass all the parameters depending on which rule I'm adding.  I'm getting the error when I don't pass the `floatingPeriodLength` property.  In other words, when floatingPeriodLength is undefined.  Is there any way to add a new pricing rule without setting some of the properties?  I haven't set them as required in the schema...

```
app.post('/addPricingRule', async function(req, res){
    console.log("/addPricingRule");
    if(!req.user) {
        handleError(res, "User not logged in", "User not logged in", 403);
    } else {
        var newRule = {};
        var aListingID = req.body.aListingID;
        var _id = req.body._id;
        var title = req.body.title;
        var event = req.body.event;
        var amount = req.body.amount;
        var scale = req.body.scale;
        var floatingPeriodStartDay = req.body.floatingPeriodStartDay;
        var floatingPeriodLength = req.body.floatingPeriodLength;
        var orphanPeriodLength = req.body.orphanPeriodLength;
        var specificDatesStartDate = req.body.specificDatesStartDate;
        var specificDatesEndDate = req.body.specificDatesEndDate;
        try {
            var accounts = await Account.find({userID: req.user._id});
            var accountIDs = [];
            accounts.forEach(function(account) {
                accountIDs.push(account._id);
            });
            var listing = await Listing.findOne({
                accountID: {$in: accountIDs},
                aListingID,
            });
            if(_id) {
                await PriceRule.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,
                    {
                        title,
                        event,
                        amount,
                        scale,
                        floatingPeriodStartDay,
                        floatingPeriodLength,
                        orphanPeriodLength,
                        specificDatesStartDate,
                        specificDatesEndDate,
                    }
                );
            } else {
                await PriceRule.create({
                    listingID: listing._id,
                    title,
                    event,
                    amount,
                    scale,
                    floatingPeriodStartDay,
                    floatingPeriodLength,
                    orphanPeriodLength,
                    specificDatesStartDate,
                    specificDatesEndDate,
                });
            }
        } catch(error) {
            handleError(res, error.message, "/addPricingRule", 400);
        }
        res.status(200).json("success");
    }
});
```

Here's the schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MessageRule = new Schema({
    listingID: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'listing'},
    message: String,
    title: String,
    event: String,
    days: Number,
    time: Number,
    minNights: {type: Number, default: 1},
    lastMinuteMessage: {type: String, default: ""},
    lastMinuteMessageEnabled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    reviewEnabled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    reviewMessage: String,
    sendMessageAfterLeavingReview: Boolean,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('MessageRule', MessageRule);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like take a copy with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var aListingID = req.body.aListingID;
var _id = req.body._id;
var fields = Object.assign({}, req.body);  // take a copy rather than assign separately 
delete fields._id;                         // discard these properties from the copy
delete fields.aListingID;
```

And then use `fields` later like

```
 await PriceRule.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, fields);
```

And when you have additional information, assign another merged copy

```
 await PriceRule.create(Object.assign({ listingID: listing._id }, fields))
```

In that way if the properties are not there then you simply are not creating a variable for them

Comment: Thanks for the answer but will this fix the error I'm getting?  I think this is a more elegant way to code (and I'll use it) but I'm not sure it solves my issue, does it?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TomKrones You are getting the error because `var floatingPeriodLength = req.body.floatingPeriodLength;` will be `undefined` when as you admit the key is not sent in the 'body' of the POST. So instead of assigning all of the keys to variables and tripping over undefined keys, just work with a copy of the request body, modified to the keys you are going to mostly use. Elegant code removes the error.